# Specific keydown error

Tags: c#, wpf

Help me

I  create a KeyDown event here:

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{    
    if(e.Key== Keys.Enter)
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Enter is pressed");
    }     
}
```

But problem is when I click "Enter" with shift or Ctlr or other key

Same result will be shown.

I want to create only Keys.Enter other command will not be shown.

Please help me

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this, but it looks like you could just check the modifiers for the associated keyboard device:

```
if (e.Key == Keys.Enter && e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.None)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool GetKeyboardState(byte[] keyState);

    private static readonly byte[] DistinctVirtualKeys = Enumerable.Range(0, 256).Select(KeyInterop.KeyFromVirtualKey)
        .Where(item => item != Key.None && item != Key.Enter).Distinct().Select(item => (byte)KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(item)).ToArray();

    public int GetDownKeysCount()
    {
        var keyboardState = new byte[256];
        GetKeyboardState(keyboardState);
        var downKeyBytes = DistinctVirtualKeys.ToList().FindAll(virtualKey => (keyboardState[virtualKey] & 0x80) != 0);
        return downKeyBytes.Count;
    }

    private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter && e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.None && GetDownKeysCount() == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter is pressed");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the Modifiers with the Enter Key:

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Enter) && Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.None)
        {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter Pressed");
        }
}
```

Comment: Note that this will use the primary keyboard device, which may not be the device which generated the event (if I'm reading the documentation correctly).